# Getting laid in the Dark Ages

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

In Dark Ages: Vampire only one method of hunting is provided: wander the streets, spot a villages, and attack him to steal his blood. There are no rules for seductive hunt. There may be two reasons for this:

- Vampires then used to have more trouble dealing with mortals, except those in Via Humanitatis.
- In Middle Ages there wasn't too easy to intimate by night.

I have a character Toreador who moves between the popular classes and uses to go to the tavern to seduce women/girls to gain his sustenance. My Storyteller allows it, but insist that it isn't very realistic, as people didn't go to taverns for that kind of action those times. My view is that the popular classes were much more libertine that we usually think.

Question is: was it so hard to have one night affair those times? Which would be the best method to seductively hunt?

Comment: Because you know, brothels and prostitution never existed before the Renaissance⸮... Wait, What?

Comment: @Sardathrion I'm not talking about prostitution, but seduction.

Comment: I know, I was being sardonic. ;)

Comment: Although you might have more luck on history.se about this...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about real-world history

Comment: @Sardathrion As it involves blood sucking, I thought it was better to post here the question, given that most people here play in medieval setting, I thought useful help could be provided.

Comment: As a side-note, let's not forget that the World of Darkness (in all its incarnations) is *not* our world, but a dark and twisted reflection of it. How dark and twisted and how far removed from our reality and history depends on your ST -- but it might be worth reminding your ST of this. ;) (So, chances are this Q is a better fit for rpg.SE than history.SE.)

Comment: ... And this question is now a "Hot Network Question" all over SE.

Comment: Rolled back to awesome title. Please leave these when they come up see: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1143/1084

Comment: This question is **on topic** based on our meta question, [Are campaign research questions on topic, part two?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1604/1204) Yes, a historian will give you an answer, but an RPG expert will give you an answer that is more specific to the RPG context (probably including RPG and WoD considerations), different to the historian's answer, and better for a World of Darkness player.

Comment: Seeing as the answer that is marked as fully solving the problem is entirely non-RPG history knowledge, it seems that this *is* off topic based on the heuristics in [Are campaign research questions on topic, part two?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1604), after all.

Comment: So, I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about real-world history.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's an online article on the homepage of the University of Rochester's River Campus Libraries titled "[Sex, Society and Medieval Women by N. M. Heckel](http://www.library.rochester.edu/robbins/sex-society)" (NSFW reading, obviously.)

It is a rather thorough, concise and comprehensive summary that might very well help you with your inquiries, and may even help you and your ST outline your party's take on how these things work in the dark and twisted World of Darkness (which is, again, not our world, but a broken mirror of it, giving the ST quite a lot of freedom to shape it to meet their taste.)

To answer your question briefly, based on the above reading: **No, it wasn't that hard to have a one night stand in those times; and the best method to seductively hunt would be either to engage in courtly love (if your rank and station permits), or to visit brothels.**

Note, please, that a longer answer would be to cite the entire article here, but that would be against the site's (in fact, both sites :)) policy. Do read that article, though.

Also note, please, that historians' opinions may very well differ on ambiguous topics. I suggest sticking by a view you (both/all) find acceptable, and developing your take on the realities of the World of Darkness from that. I think the article I'm linking is quite a good source / resource for this topic... though (full disclosure) I'm no historian. :)

Comment: For the carnal pleasures of the lower classes, I also recommend to read the poems of Francois Villon (the real one, not the Prince of Paris). He lived then and there, was of low class and lower morals, yet a very charismatic and energetic poet, and his poems are fantastic. Much to be learned from them.